# Get sudoers information for all users on a server

Tags: unix, sudo, sudoers

I want to collect information on what sudoers actions a user can perform on a server.  From what I've [read](http://www.courtesan.com/sudo/sudo.man.html), you can do this with the command `sudo -l -U username`.  However, one server that I have has a slightly older version of sudo (1.6.7p5) and the -U option doesn't seem to exist (I don't own the server so I can't just upgrade to a newer version of sudo).

Has anyone ever had to collect sudoers information for all users on a server?  How would you recommend doing it?

EDIT: This has to be an automated process, so "just look at the sudoers file" won't work.

Comment: If you at least have `root` privileges, you can install a newer `sudo` to your home directory (`./configure --prefix ~/usr` or your location of choice), run it with `-U`, then simply remove it.

Comment: I don't have root privileges or permission to install a newer sudo.

Answer (score 0):

As `root`:

```
cat /etc/sudoers > /home/username/sudoerprivs  
cd /home/username  
chown username:username sudoerprivs
```

Comment: This has to be an automated process, so just visually looking at the file won't work.

Comment: Can't you just search through the file with grep and awk based on the lines you need?

Comment: @Diablomarcus - yes you could.  I made a copy in this method so it could be moved to another computer in an enterprise environment.  Then you could launch shell scripts containing grep or awk at a hierarchy of directories/files to programmatically check ALL computers.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do `visudo` and see what options each user has.

Comment: This has to be an automated process, so just visually looking at the file won't work.